# check if input has a number or just letters then echo result on submit

Tags: php, phpmailer

Im making a form that checks the Name input and echos results when the submit button is pressed using a IF statement. But i cant get it to work. What am i doing wrong?

```
<form id="AUTO"   method="post" action="" novalidate>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="miles" value=""/>
    <div id="contact_name">FULL NAME: *<br>
        <input id="element_2_1" name="name" class="element text" size="15" 
            maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="FULL NAME">
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>

$Name = $_POST['Name'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //checks name field for a number if one exist echo has a number
    if (preg_match('|[0-9]', $Name)) {
        echo 'has a number';
    } else {
        echo 'Does not contain a number';
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all turn on error reporting while developing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: You can print `$_POST` variable with [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and see what you are receiving

Comment: error_log is in my cpanel does the same thing just found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="AUTO"   method="post" action="" novalidate>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="miles" value=""/>
<div id="contact_name">FULL NAME: *<br>
<input id="Name" name="Name" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="15" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value=""></div>   
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>




<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$Name = $_POST['Name'] ;




if (preg_match('#[0-9]#',$Name)){
echo 'has number';
}else{
    echo 'no number';

}





?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form input tag is named `name` however you are trying to get value POST index of `Name`.

Correct would be

```
$Name = $_POST['name'] ;
```

Keep the case of names.

Comment: He's gonna need to add something like if(isset($_POST['name']){ //code } to avoir some errors. The pattern is wrong too, something like /^[0-9]$/ should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Forms are key are sensitive if you set the form name as lowercase

```
    <input id="element_2_1" name="name" class="element text" size="15"
maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="FULL NAME">
```

and in server side you should catch it as lowercase like this below.

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
```

That's how you can call the variable from the form in your server side.

Hope this helps you to solve your problem.

Thanks